# Flutter Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a project I did before null safety was introduced, now my code has a lot of errors and I want to downgrade my flutter and dart to before null safety. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, your title is not matching with your question. There is also nothing what did you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Because your title is different from your question. I will answer you only to question.

Inside terminal:

`flutter downgrade v1.x.x` you can see flutter versions [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tags) (please use the version that you had before the upgrade). More about downgrade find [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-downgrade) please.

After that, run `flutter doctor -v` to check the version.